# Spring Jersey return proxy objects in JSON

Tags: json, spring, jersey, spring-data

I'm using `Spring Data Repository` to persistence objects. I'm trying to return them by REST web api (`Jersey`) and getting an error, but when i'm trying to return normal POJO object, all looks fine, Jersey parse object to JSON and i'm getting response 200 code.

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Document test() {
    Document d = documentRepository.findOne(123L);

    return d; // response code 500 without any stack trace

    return new Document(); // normal JSON object in response content
}
```

My dependencies for jersey:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can i return proxy object from spring data repository, or List of these objects ?

Comment: Did you make sure that documentRepository.findOne() method indeed returned proper document  and not null ?

Comment: Yes, I debugged code, it is proxy object

Comment: Please try like this:  return Response.ok(d,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build(); Change the return type to Response.

Comment: Same problem - code 500

Comment: Did you annotate your Document class with the annotation @XmlRootElement(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement)? And also it's better if you print the debug logs to console. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014184/jersey-returns-500-when-trying-to-return-an-xml-response

Comment: Not helped, but when i'm trying make a copy of object then Jersey return correct json. Only proxy object causes error.

Comment: I'd advice you to print the logs to console so that you can know what's going wrong. I'm suspecting that something going wring while converting the proxy object(of Document type) to JSON, may be because you forgot to map some attributes correctly in  Document  bean.