# jersey return 500 when trying return an XML

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a problem with using Jersey 2.29. Its simple example. I managed to return text-plain, but if I trying return XML i get 500 error.

My steps:

Start server. Go to `http://localhost:8080/demorest/webapi/aliens`. I 
I'll get 500.

when I rewrote this example to return text-plain, everything was ok. But with XML is a problem.

I looked here:
[Jersey returns 500 when trying to return an XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014184/jersey-returns-500-when-trying-to-return-an-xml-response)
But its not work to me.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.demorest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Alien.java

```
package com.test.demorest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {

    private String name;
    private int points;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

AlienResource.java

```
package com.test.demorest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Alien getAlien() {
        System.out.println("getAlien called...");
        Alien a1 = new Alien();
        a1.setName("Adam");
        a1.setPoints(23);

        return a1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had the same issue, the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the dependencies in your pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use 2 constructors for the class. I found the solution hard but it worked.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {

private String name;
private int points;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}
public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public Alien(){
}
public Alien(String name,int points)
{
   this.name=name;
   this.points=points;
}
}
```